# Input type=date spin control buttons on the right are not vertically aligned

Tags: css, html

I am using this code to create a date picker; the browser is Chrome 54.

```
<input type="date">
```

CSS:

```
input {
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 35px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In the result, the buttons on the right do not have proper vertical alignment, they align to the top.

[image: input type=date buttons alignment problem]

Is there a way to fix it so that they align to the middle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage with padding..

```css
input {
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 35px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding:5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type='date'>
```